# In Settings -> Apps -> AppName, is there a way to password-protect the permissions menu?

Tags: android, permissions, password-protection

I've installed a filtering software on my son's Android phone, but he knows how to bypass it by revoking the Phone permissions in the filter app's settings.  Is there a way for me to password-protect the page where app permission can be changed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's the filtering software's responsibility to prevent itself from being bypassed. If it can't, just switch to another one. Plus, many phones themselves have student mode or visitor mode, you can setup a password for the account you use, to confine your child in a visitor account.